# Android, How to filter social sharing for having just Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, social-networking

In my project I need to share some information into Just Facebook and Twitter. Currently when you use following codes, android offers list of all social networks that you have in your mobile phone.

```
public void share(String subject,String text) {
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with:"));
}
```

The requirement is just showing Facebook and Twitter in this list. Is it possible to filter this list in order to have these two?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can't do this directly within an Intent, but I believe you can implement your own dialog to do so.

Answer (score 8):

```
    Button btnshare=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnshare);
        btnshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Share(getShareApplication(),"Hello Text Share");
            }
        });

    private List<String> getShareApplication(){
        List<String> mList=new ArrayList<String>();
        mList.add("com.facebook.katana");
        mList.add("com.twitter.android");
        mList.add("com.google.android.gm");
        return mList;

    }
    private void Share(List<String> PackageName,String Text) {
        try
        {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    targetedShare.setType("text/plain"); // put here your mime type
                    if (PackageName.contains(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase())) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Text);
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could query for the activities that match the intent and then filter for the package names of the Twitter and Facebook apps since the package name of an app never changes. Then put these results in a custom dialog.

Using something like this you could filter the results by package name:

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
List<ResolveInfo> riList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo ri : riList) {
    ActivityInfo ai = ri.activityInfo;
    String pkg = ai.packageName;
    if (pkg.equals("com.facebook.katana") || pkg.equals("com.twitter.android")) {

        // Add to the list of accepted activities.

        // There's a lot of info available in the
        // ResolveInfo and ActivityInfo objects: the name, the icon, etc.

        // You could get a component name like this:
        ComponentName cmp = new ComponentName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear Ken, Therefore it shows is not possible to filter the list. I'll test your suggestion and later i'll tell the result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you mean but you can use the Android built-in sharing menu...

You can share a URL to **Facebook, Twitter, Gmail** and more (as long as the apps are installed on your device) using Intents:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
```

**Don't forget to insert this to the Manifest.xml:**

```
<activity android:name="ShareLink">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
            </activity>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think he means how can he not have Gmail and other apps in there though, just Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: thanks dear Mike, This code is as same as mine. As mentioned by Ken, I need to filter the list in order to have just those two social networks.